# how to find the series $x + x^{1 + \frac{1}{2}} + x^{1 + \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}} +...$ is convergent.

Tags: real-analysis

The series $x + x^{1 + \frac{1}{2}} + x^{1 + \frac{1}{2}+ \frac{1}{3}} +...$
is convergent if

(A) $x>e$

(B) $x<e $

(C) $x<1/e$

(D) $x>1/e$

I think the answer is C, but I could not determine the condition... how to solve it. Plz help.

Comment: As the others are obviously wrong (no convergerce for $x = 1$ and $x= 10$) ... (C) ist the answer ...

Comment: I think it is difficult to solve analytically, but all other than (C) can be pretty easily ruled out.

Comment: What if (D') $1/e<x<1\;$? How to exclude it?

Answer (score 7):

We have
\begin{align*}
  x^{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i} &\le x^{\log n + 1}\\
   &= x \cdot \exp(\log n\cdot \log x)\\
   &= x \cdot n^{\log x}
\end{align*}
and
\begin{align*}
  x^{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i} &\ge x^{\log n}\\
   &= \exp(\log n\cdot \log x)\\
   &= n^{\log x}
\end{align*}
and hence
\[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac 1i} < \infty \iff \sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{\log x} < \infty \]
which is true exactly for $\log x < -1\iff x < \frac 1e$.

Comment: How is your first inequality true. At n=1, $ x^1=x,x^{log(1+1)}=x^{0.3010299}$ your inequality doesn't satisfy

Comment: No. Not $x^{\log(n+1)}$, but $x^{\log n + 1}$, which I should‘ve written as $x^{1+\log n}$. @SaurabhRana

Answer (score 0):

Nth term of series is given by $u_n=x^{\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{1}{i}}$
[Logarithmic test](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3668889/prove-that-sum-a-n-converges-if-g-1-and-diverges-otherwise?noredirect=1) says

> Suppose $\sum_{ n \geq 1} a_n $ is a series of positive terms. Suppose
> that
>
> $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} n \ln \dfrac{ a_n }{a_{n+1} } = g $$
> and if $g>1$ series is convergent and divergent if $g<1$.

now firstly take $x\ge0$, at $x=0$ series converges, and at $x=1$ series diverges(option B discarded).
Now $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \cdots$ is divergent series, so $\lim( 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \cdots)$ tends to infinity so if $x>1$, $lim(x^{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4} \cdots}) \ne 0$, so not convergent for $x>1$(option A discarded).

applying log test for $0<x<1$, $$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \log \dfrac{ a_n }{a_{n+1} }=n \log(x^{\frac{-1}{n}})=-\log x$$

so if $-\log x > 1$ or $x<\frac{1}{e}$ , series converges and if $x>\frac{1}{e}$ series diverges.

For negative values of $x$ , series is absolutely convergent for $x<\frac{1}{e}$ so it is convergent in $x<\frac{1}{e}$ region.