# Test the convergence of the series $\frac{1}{3}+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{2}}+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}}+\cdots$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Test the convergence of the series
>   $\frac{1}{3}+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{2}}+\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}}+\cdots$

The $n$-th term of the series is $t_n=\left( \dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\cdots+\frac{1}{n}}$.

Now, $\dfrac{t_{n+1}}{t_n}\to1$ as $n\to \infty$. Thus D'alembert ratio test fails. How can I check convergency?

**Added:** The given solution is quite complicated. I am looking for a simpler one.

Comment: Try applying the limit comparison test with $n^{-ln3}$.

Comment: Also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/209711/42969